# R: Loop to create new data frames in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a loop which creates a number of files for a VCS Station that are named according to their station name. Below is the code that does this for one station, and I am trying to turn it into a loop so I can do it for 68 stations.  (i.e. if I was copying and pasting I would be replacing the P205187 with a different station name, say P205200). I have the individual station names (e.g. P205187) in a dataframe called VCS.Sites.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  New R user here and I am stuck!

```
P205187 <- VCSrawdata[VCSrawdata$Network_ID=="P205187",]  #create a file for VCS station P205187
  #clean up after subset
  P205187$Network_ID <- factor(P205187$Network_ID)


# create annual file for VCS station P205187
P205187_annual <- group_by(P205187,Year,DESCRIPTION)
P205187_annual <- summarise(P205187_annual,Sum_Annual = sum(Value), Mean_Annual = mean(Value), CountDays=n())

# create monthly file for VCS station P205187
P205187_monthly <- group_by(P205187,Year, Month,DESCRIPTION)
P205187_monthly <- summarise(P205187_monthly,Sum_Monthly = sum(Value),Mean_monthly = mean(Value),CountDays=n())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it quite well with an lapply loop. Something like this:

```
list_of_ids <- c("List be here")

monthly <- function(id){
  P205187 <- VCSrawdata[VCSrawdata$Network_ID==id,]  #create a file for VCS station P205187
  #clean up after subset
  P205187$Network_ID <- factor(P205187$Network_ID)
  
  
  # create annual file for VCS station P205187
  P205187_annual <- group_by(P205187,Year,DESCRIPTION)
  P205187_annual <- summarise(P205187_annual,Sum_Annual = sum(Value), Mean_Annual = mean(Value), CountDays=n())
  
  # create monthly file for VCS station P205187
  P205187_monthly <- group_by(P205187,Year, Month,DESCRIPTION)
  P205187_monthly <- summarise(P205187_monthly,Sum_Monthly = sum(Value),Mean_monthly = mean(Value),CountDays=n())
  
  return(P205187_monthly)
}

monthlies <- lapply(list_of_ids, monthly)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is for writing csvs. We can use `group_map` from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) to loop through all of the stations and write csvs.

```r
library(dplyr)

VCSrawdata %>%
    group_by(Network_ID) %>%
    group_walk(~ {
        .x%>%
            group_by(Year, DESCRIPTION) %>%
            summarize(sum_annual = sum(Value),
                      mean_annual = mean(Value),
                      countDays = n())%>%
            write.csv(file = paste0(.y$Network_ID, "_annual_csv"))
        
        .x%>%
            group_by(Year, Month, DESCRIPTION) %>%
            summarize(sum_month = sum(Value),
                      mean_month = mean(Value),
                      countDays = n())%>%
            write.csv(file = paste0(.y$Network_ID, "_month_csv")) 
    }
    )
```

Things to note:

1. The `.x` is referring to the the grouped tibble that is split by `Network_ID`
2. The `.y` is referring to the grouping. In this case, we only have `Network_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply generalize your process in a defined method, then pass station names as a parameter in a loop or *apply* function to iterate through stations. With this approach you avoid *many* separate objects flooding global environment and instead use a **single** named list of many underlying elements for better serialization and organization.

```
summarize_stations <- function(station_name) { 

   tmp_df <- VCSrawdata[VCSrawdata$Network_ID==station_name,] 
   tmp_df$Network_ID <- factor(tmp_df$Network_ID) 

   # create annual file for VCS station
   tmp_annual <- summarise(group_by(tmp,Year,DESCRIPTION),
                           Sum_Annual = sum(Value), 
                           Mean_Annual = mean(Value), 
                           CountDays=n()) 

   # create monthly file for VCS station
   tmp_monthly <- summarise(group_by(tmp, Year, Month,DESCRIPTION),
                            Sum_Annual = sum(Value), 
                            Mean_Annual = mean(Value), 
                            CountDays=n())

   # RETURN NAMED LIST OF BOTH AGGREGATIONS
   return(list(annual=tmp_annual, monthly=tmp_monthly))
}

station_list <- sapply(VCS.Sites$station_names, summarize_stations, simplify=FALSE)


# ACCESS UNDERLYING ELEMENTS
station_list$P205187$annual
station_list$P205187$monthly
...
```

---

You can even use `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) to subset `VCSrawdata` by `Network_ID` (assuming it includes all your needed stations). To do so, slightly adjust function to receive a data frame as parameter which allows you to skip subset line.

```
summarize_stations <- function(tmp_df) { 

  # REMOVE SUBSET LINE
  # tmp_df <- VCSrawdata[VCSrawdata$Network_ID=="P205187",] 
  
  ...keep same code as above    
}

station_list <- by(VCSrawdata, VCSrawdata$Network_ID, FUN=summarize_stations)


# ACCESS UNDERLYING ELEMENTS
station_list$P205187$annual
station_list$P205187$monthly
...
```